# Sending email attachment - Converting CSV file to bytes removes line breaks

Tags: powershell, csv, base64, byte, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to use the MS Graph cmdlet `Send-MgUserMail` to send an email and include a CSV attachment.

If I do it like this, it works fine, and the attachment is fine.

**Sample CSV attachment**

```
"App","AppId","Date","User"
"App1","43a9087d-8551-47d5-9869-3287736ce7c3","2023/01/26","me@email.com"
"App2","f33750cd-c79b-43be-8e55-ee14d163e2b3","2024/01/26","me@email.com"
```

**Working code**

```
$attachment   = "C:\Users\Me\Downloads\SampleFile.csv"
$base64string = [Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($attachment))

$params = @{
    UserId = "me@email.com"
    BodyParameter = @{
        Message = @{
            Subject = "Test Email"
            Body    = @{
                ContentType = "Html"
                Content     = "This is sample text."
            }
            ToRecipients = @(
                @{
                    EmailAddress = @{
                        Address = "toAddress@email.com"
                    }
                }
            )
            Attachments = @(
                @{
                    "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment"
                    Name         = "SampleFile.csv"
                    ContentType  = "text/csv"
                    ContentBytes = $base64string
                }
            )
        }
        SaveToSentItems = "false"
    }
}
 
Send-MgUserMail @params
```

**Objective**

What I would like is to attach the CSV, **without** having an actual saved file. The content would be from memory, like so.

```
$output = @(
    [PSCustomObject] @{
        App = "App1"
        AppId = "43a9087d-8551-47d5-9869-3287736ce7c3"
        Date  = "2023/01/26"
        User  = "me@email.com"
    },
    [PSCustomObject] @{
        App = "App2"
        AppId = "f33750cd-c79b-43be-8e55-ee14d163e2b3"
        Date  = "2024/01/26"
        User  = "me@email.com"
    }
)

$attachment = $output | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

$bytes         = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($attachment)
$base64string  = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

My issue when I do this is the CSV content is entirely on 1 line, there's no more line breaks.

**Issue Sample CSV Output**

```
"App","AppId","Date","User" "App1","43a9087d-8551-47d5-9869-3287736ce7c3","2023/01/26","me@email.com" "App2","f33750cd-c79b-43be-8e55-ee14d163e2b3","2024/01/26","me@email.com"
```

How can I convert this properly?

Comment: try converting your array of strings to a single multiline string first: `$attachment = $output | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-String`

Comment: haha <3 what happens is, `ConvertTo-Csv` outputs an array of strings and they dont have new line characters (CRLF in Windows, LF in Linux) so when you get the bytes of `$attachment` those bytes are missing the new lines. `Out-String` ensures the structure of your Csv is preserved. You could also use `($output | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join [Environment]::NewLine`

Comment: Also `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(...)` coerces `$Attachment` to be a string and when you coerce an array into a string in PowerShell, it is joined by `$OFS` (a white space character) hence why you get a single line joined by whitespaces when decoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was given in comments but to give it closure, what happens is that [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7.3) outputs an array of strings and they don't have new line characters (CRLF in Windows, LF in Linux), before getting the bytes of your Csv you need to convert this array into a single multi-line string, for this you can use `Out-String`:

```
$attachment = $output | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-String
```

Or join them by a new line character to preserve the structure:

```
$attachment = ($output | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join [Environment]::NewLine
```

Also, [`[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=net-7.0#system-text-encoding-getbytes(system-string)) which has a string type argument is coercing your array into a string and when you coerce an array into a string in PowerShell, it is joined by [$OFS (a white space character by default)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#ofs) hence why you get a single line joined by whitespaces when decoding the base64 string.

---

Another way this could've been done is by assigning `$OFS` the value of a new line character:

```
$attachment = $output | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
$OFS = [System.Environment]::NewLine
$bytes         = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($attachment)
$base64string  = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$OFS = ' '

# Decoding should look as expected
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString(
    [Convert]::FromBase64String($base64string)
)
```